# Magento 2 Wrong products count on Advanced Search & Catalog Product List

Tags: magento-2.1, product, catalogsearch

I am using `Magento 2` and have noticed a wrong products **count** on Advanced Search & Catalog Product List.

For example for Advanced search it may show 3 products and total count will say 10. Same for Catalog Product List Widget total is incorrect. We have only configurable products visible on front end we have disable all static products.

any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I think this was mentioned sometimes

See this

https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.1/app/code/Magento/CatalogSearch/Model/Search/FilterMapper/TermDropdownStrategy.php#L101

```
    $this->storeManager->getWebsite()->getId()
```

This was fixed on 2.2 and 2.3 but not 2.1. It should be

```
    $this->storeManager->getStore()->getId()
```

Try to override this model or use **cweagans/composer-patches** to patch. Hope this help

Comment: I think the issue is with total count, seems like it is counting out of stock products too, on page 2 sometimes is shows like `Items 25 to 24 of 43 total`

Comment: So check Inventory settings from Catalog Configurations

Comment: it seems like if a configurable product's all children are out of stock the configurable is still not out of stock and magento is counting those too